# Can the idea of Affine (relaxed Linear) Types be implemented in an untyped setting to enable safe mutations?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, mutation, linear-types

It'd be useful if I could use safe in-place destructive updates on `Array`s and `Map`s every now and then. Linear types are a technique to allow safe mutations by restricting the consumption of values to an *exactly once* semantics. While it seems not possible to implement *exactly once* in Javascript, here is an implementation of the relaxed *at most once* variant, which corresponds to affine types:

```js
class LinearProxy {
  constructor() {
    this.once = false;
  }

  get(o, k) {
    if (this.once)
      throw new TypeError("non-linear type usage");

    else this.once = true;

    if (k === "run")
      return once(f => {
        const r = f(o);

        if (r === o)
          throw new TypeError("non-linear type usage");

        else return r;
      });

    return o[k];
  }

  set(o, k, v) {
    if (this.once)
      throw new TypeError("non-linear type usage");

    o[k] = v;
    return true;
  }
}

const linear = o => new Proxy(o, new LinearProxy());

const once = f => {
  let called = false;

  return x => {
    if (called)
      throw new TypeError("non-linear type usage");

    else {
      called = true;
      return f(x);
    }
  };
};

const run = f => tx =>
  tx["run"] (f);
  
const id = x => x;
const last = xs => xs[xs.length - 1];
const dup = xs => [...xs, ...xs];

const xs = linear([1,2,3]),
  ys = linear([1,2,3]),
  zs = linear([1,2,3]);

xs[3] = 4;
xs[4] = 5;

console.log(
  "run(last) (xs):",
  run(last) (xs)); // 5

try {run(last) (xs)}
catch(e) {console.log("run(last) (xs):", e.message)} // type error (A)

try {const x = xs[4]}
catch(e) {console.log("x = xs[4]:", e.message)} // type error (A)

try {xs[0] = 11}
catch(e) {console.log("xs[0] = 11:", e.message)} // type error (B)

try {run(id) (ys)}
catch(e) {console.log("run(id) (ys):", e.message)} // type error (C)

console.log(run(dup) (zs)); // [1,2,3,1,2,3] (D)
```

Subsequent read access (A) and write access (B) of once consumed linear types throw a type error. The attempt to gain immediate access to the reference (C) of a linear type also throws a type error. The latter is just a naive check to prevent returning the reference by accident. One could easily bypass it, so we must rely on convention for this case.

However, `D` is not affine, because the argument is consumed twice. Does the fact that the non-linear use happens within a function scope means that it is still (relatively) safe? Is there a more clever way to implement linear types in Javascript?